# pjsip - iOS build error

Tags: ios, ios7.1, pjsip

I see the following build error in Xcode when building for iOS. I have spent some time looking at the make file etc but couldn't identify the issue. It has been working so far. There has been no change in source or make file. I think it is not related to iOS.

```
.pjmedia-test-arm-apple-darwin9.depend:324: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Any insight/clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found the issue. The file was hidden under `.../pjsip/build/`. The dependency files that PJSIP generates gets corrupted if you stopped an earlier build abruptly. Just delete the offending file.

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#missing-sep-err

Just find all the depend files and delete them all before you start a new build.

```
find . -name "*.depend" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: this was driving me nuts